# Exporting a large data from oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to export a large amount of data from oracle something like 7 million records and then import it in mysql. but during the exporting a data from oracle(using oracle sql developer), the sql developer freezed. Any ideas how to export a large amount of data from oracle and then import it in the mysql.

Comment: you can use method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14209971/copying-a-very-large-table-from-one-db2-to-another-using-perl-and-dbi

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need an ETL tool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)
There is one open source good product called Pentaho Data Integration.

Website: http://community.pentaho.com/

Download: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?133266-Kettle-4-4-0-stable-has-been-posted-to-SourceForge-net

How to use it: http://pldwh.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/pentaho-data-integration-how-to-use.html

**NOTE:** You do not have to create any repository (file/db) you can just create:

a new transformation -> add table input and table output -> define connections

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer doesn't handle large data sets very well, but SQL*Plus is very capable in that respect and has been used for this for decades. Spooling out a file of that size is no problem, and it's a free tool of course.

You have to pay attention to various settings to override the default headings, linesize, pagesize, feedback etc..

Run tests on a select of about 1,000 records to establish that you have the correct settings. Off the top of my head ...

```
set heading off
set feedback off
set echo off
set termout off
set linesize 2000
set define off
set trimspool on
```

There may be a few I've forgotten -- if you see undesirable formatting issues in the output post a followup if you can't resolve them yourself.